# Excel Formula Help Needed

Tags: excel

Here is 2 columns of data. I need to write a formula to compare the two columns. The end result is I want to know which in column A are not in column B.

COL-A COL-B

1023        1023

1024        1024

1025        1025

1026        1026

1028        1028

1029        1029

Can we write formula for this? or we have to write macro?
I am not in advance to write macro it its required :( help me please

Comment: How do you need to show the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this formula in `C1`:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE)))
```

And expand downwards. It will be `TRUE` if the value in column `A` exists in column `B`.

For the record, your example data is identical in both columns, so it will always be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is your question, but to compare row by row, without programming AND without formula:

- highlight the 2 columns,
- then press ctrl+G (shortcut for Go To),
- click on Special button
- Select Row differences

That's it, Excel has selected all cells in second column that are different from the first column. Just click on a color button to keep the result visible.

You can of course program that as well. try recording it if you're nowhere with programming.
(look Ma...no hands !)